# what is the time complexity of heapify a heap

Tags: time-complexity, heap, master-theorem

The lecture of data structure shows that, the formula of heapify is: 
T(n) ≤ T(2n/3) + Θ(1). 
But then it says that 
"By case 2 of the Master Theorem, T(n) = O(lg n), Thus, Heapify takes logarithmic time." I don't really get it, what are the values of a,b,c and d, and why this case belongs to the second case of the theorem, and the result is O(lg n)?

thx

Master Theorem is here
[image]

Comment: Look at your recursion relation and compare it to the general form given in the link. You should be able to deduce `b, c, d` from there. `a` doesn't matter because it is only an additive constant.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog it is not a link to [Master theorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) but a link to an image. OP, try reading the link in my comment.

Comment: so, b is 3/2, d is 1.  d<b. so this should be the first case of the theorem?

Answer (score 0):

Consider, T(n) = aT(n/b) + n^c for n>1

There are three cases (note that b is the log base)

```
(1)  if logb a < c, T(n)=Θ(n^c),

(2)  if logb a = c, T (n) = Θ(n^c log n),

(3)  if logb a > c, T(n) = Θ(n^(logb a)).
```

In your case you have

```
T(n) = T(2n/3) + n^0
```

We can say,

```
n^0 here because Θ(1) = Θ(n^0)
```

So,

```
a = 1, b = 3/2, and c = 0
```

We can easily verity that

```
log3/2  1 = 0
```

Thus we see that we need to use case 2

```
logb a = c
```

So,

```
T(n) = Θ(n^c log n) = Θ(n^0 log n) = Θ(log n)
```

**Looking at the image that you posted**

Observe case 2.

It says that

```
Θ(n log n) if d = b
```

In general it is,

```
Θ(n^i log n) if d = b^i

d = b^i  implies logb d = i
```

But for the sake of (hopefully) clarifying

d = 1 and b = 3/2 (and as shown above) i = 0

So,

d = b^i is true

I used different letters here but this is identical to the way I described above.  I did the same thing twice, once using the letters in your post to hopefully clear things up for you.  No matter how you want to look at it, you would use case 2.